# PHPMailer doesn't work on CentOS

Tags: php, email, yii, centos

I got a contact us page using PHP. Like all contact us, after someone clicking send, it will send a warning to my email.

The problem is it doesn't work. The script works perfectly in my localhost, it doesn't work only on the server and it doesn't show any error.

> ```
>         $default_path = get_include_path();
>         set_include_path(dirname(__FILE__)."/../");
>         require_once("extensions/PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php");
>         set_include_path($default_path);
>         $mail = new PHPMailer();
>         $mail->IsSMTP(); // send via SMTP
>         $mail->SMTPSecure="ssl";
>         $mail->Host="smtp.gmail.com";
>         $mail->SMTPDebug =0;
>         $mail->Port=465;
>         $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // turn on SMTP authentication
>
>         $mail->Username = Yii::app()->params['sender_email']; // SMTP username
>         $mail->Password = Yii::app()->params['sender_password']; // SMTP password
>         $webmaster_email = Yii::app()->params['webmaster_email']; //Reply to this email ID
>         $mail->From = $email_address;
>         $mail->FromName = "Webmaster";
>         $mail->AddAddress($email_address,"");
>         $mail->AddReplyTo($webmaster_email,"Webmaster");
>         $mail->WordWrap = 70; // set word wrap
>         //$mail->AddAttachment("/var/tmp/file.tar.gz"); // attachment
>         //$mail->AddAttachment("/tmp/image.jpg", "new.jpg"); // attachment
>         $mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML
>         $mail->Subject = $mailcontent->subject;
>         $mail->Body = $mailcontent->body;
>         //$mail->AltBody = "This is the body when user views in plain text format"; //Text Body
>         $mail->Send();
> ```

I think it's because of server misconfiguration(this is my first time settings a server), but i didn't know what i did wrong.

The firewall already set to allow every traffic, so it's not firewall problem.

No error and no results makes me very confused.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after I checked everything, it turns out google block my email access from the server because of suspicious activity.

To unblock this, you need to visit this page : https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

and then run the script again.